# How to install Elasticsearch with AWS EKS

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks

I wanna install Elasticsearch in AWS EKS. But [Elasticsearch is not recommended EFS Storage](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/cloud-aws-best-practices.html#:%7E:text=is%20not%20recommended%20or%20supported).

So I want to install Elasticsearch using AWS EKS + EC2 (Management Node Group) + EBS.

I'm curious about three things.

**First,** EKS is a managed Kubernetes service. Should we install Elasticsearch by installing one node (EC2) and Kubernetes in EC2?
[image]

**Second,** create three EC2s, install elasticsearch with Docker for each instance, and connect clustering
[image]

**Three,** whether Elasticsearch can be installed with the EKS Fargate.

It may be an ignorant question, but I would appreciate it if you could give me an idea on how to reliably build Elasticsearch in EKS.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simpler way to install Elasticsearch (or ELK in general) is to use [EKS with EFS driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html). Then you can use Helm / Operator to install Elastic.

If you strive for highest Elastic performance, or/and have bigger cluster, then I'd go with your Second solution, so install each Elastic node on a separate EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you for reply. 

I understand that configuring with EFS will damage the es index, is it okay?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Helm chart to deploy the elastic search on EKS cluster.

https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/main/elasticsearch

So by default, it will use the storage class, which will be disk and it will give better performance. Accordingly, you can change the storage class and disk changes as per requirement in the helm chart.

it's also good to deploy the Elasticsearch on separate nodes however creating networking and managing might not be as easy as on Kubernetes cluster.